# The above error occurred in the <ArticlePage> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I Am Making A Article Page Using ReactJs Everything Is Fine But I Am Facing Errors While I Am Clicking One Article It Is Not Showing On Screen While Inspecting There Errors Goes Like
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
The above error occurred in the  component:

Article Page JS

```
import React from 'react';
import ArticlesList from '../components/ArticlesList';
import NotFoundPage from './NotFoundPage';
import articleContent from './article-content';

const ArticlePage = ({ match }) => {
    const name = match.params.name;
    const article = articleContent.find(article => article.name === name);

    if (!article) return <NotFoundPage />

    const otherArticles = articleContent.filter(article => article.name !== name);

    return (
        <>
        <h1>{article.title}</h1>
        {article.content.map((paragraph, key) => (
            <p key={key}>{paragraph}</p>
        ))}
        <h3>Other Articles:</h3>
        <ArticlesList articles={otherArticles} />
        </>
    );
}

export default ArticlePage;
```

ArticlesLists Js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const ArticlesList = ({ articles }) => (
    <>
    {articles.map((article, key) => (
        <Link className="article-list-item" key={key} to={`/article/${article.name}`}>
            <h3>{article.title}</h3>
            <p>{article.content[0].substring(0, 150)}...</p>
        </Link>
    ))}
    </>
);

export default ArticlesList;
```

Comment: match is undefined in the ArticlePage. How is it passed down?

Comment: The `match` prop is undefined. Please update your question to share how this `ArticlePage` is being rendered and what props are being passed to it. Please also confirm what version of `react-router-dom` you are using by running `npm list react-router-dom` from your project's root directory. If you recent updated to `react-router-dom@6` then there are quite a few breaking changes you should be aware of. See [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The `match` prop is undefined. For whatever reason this `ArticlePage` component isn't receiving a defined `match` prop.

## Solution

Regardless of `react-router-dom` version (v5 or v6), since `ArticlePage` is a function component you have a `useParams` React hook available to you to access the currently matched `Route`'s route path params.

- `react-router-dom@5` [useParams](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams)
- `react-router-dom@6` [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams)

ArticlePage

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const ArticlePage = () => {
  const { name } = useParams();

  const article = articleContent.find(article => article.name === name);

  if (!article) return <NotFoundPage />;

  const otherArticles = articleContent.filter(article => article.name !== name);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{article.title}</h1>
      {article.content.map((paragraph, key) => (
        <p key={key}>{paragraph}</p>
      ))}
      <h3>Other Articles:</h3>
      <ArticlesList articles={otherArticles} />
    </>
  );
};
```